# Why do I seem to need to check for a retrieved array's length for my Fetch API to work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

I'm new to React and am using the Fetch API to retrieve data from an external JSON file.

I've noticed something about how it works that I don't fully understand. In each tutorial I've read it seems you need to wrap the output in a conditional like `{data.length > 0 && ( // Do something )}` for it to work.

EG with my code:

```
  const [data,setData]=useState([]);
  const getData=()=>{
    fetch('https://www.someplace.com/jsonfile'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
    )
      .then(function(response){
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(myJson) {
        setData(myJson);
      });
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    getData()
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {data.length > 0 && ( // If I remove this is breaks
          <Welcome text={"This data is from a JSON feed: " + data[1].title}/>
        )}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
```

If I change

```
        {data.length > 0 && (
          <Welcome text={"This data is from a JSON feed: " + data[1].title}/>
        )}
```

To just

```
          <Welcome text={"This data is from a JSON feed: " + data[1].title}/>
```

The App still compiles, but I get the error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`

In my browser's console.

Now, I'd expect that error if the code failed to fetch the JSON file but if I put the length check conditional back it works no matter what.

Why does it seem that adding that conditional makes the Fetch work? Is this because the Fetch API is called multiple times and always fails the first time?

Comment: If you have an empty array you can't retrieve the title of a non-existent object from that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial values are `data = []`. React will load the Welcome component once the view is loaded and trying to access `data[1].title` which is unavailable at the initial state. that's the reason for the error. Try:

```js
data[1]?.title || ""
```

In your Welcome component. Remember, `fetch` is an async task and will not be ready on Load ie when `useEffect()` is called. [Conditional rendering](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering)